# can't find css3 in package controll panel of sublime text3

Tags: sublimetext3

I can't find css3 in package controll panel of sublime text3 and it exist in https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS3. I use windows platform.

Comment: The package controll panel can't show all result of searching

Comment: Do you already have it installed? It won't show up in `Package Control: Install Packages` if it has already been installed.

Comment: I wirte" Package Control:" in panel open by cmd " ctrl+shift+p",and it will show up "install package" and "enable package" ,so i think the package controll already been installed.

Comment: Yes, Package Control itself is now installed by default in Sublime Text 3. What I meant is that if you write `Package Control:`, then select `Install Package` and type in `CSS3`, if nothing shows up, that means the CSS3 package is already installed on your computer.